# How to fix ASP.NET Core Web API sub object creating problem?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I ran into a problem I can't create an object (does not works post action method). Please help!

These are my entities in my ASP.NET Core Web API (.Net7) project:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public BookDetail BookDetail { get; set; }
}

public class BookDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Foreign key
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    // navigation properties
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

My `BooksController` does not work for the `post` request:

```
[HttpPost("Create")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> CreateAsync(Book book)
{
    if (book == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    _db.Books.Add(book);

    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetByIdAsync), new { id = book.Id }, book);
}

[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> GetByIdAsync(int id)
{
    var book = await _db.Books.FindAsync(id);

    if (book == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(book);
}
```

Swagger error is:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-2695d8ae6781a68ca32420345ecf40a1-9851e26a3bcb27f2-00",
  "errors": {
    "book": [
      "The book field is required."
    ],
    "$.bookDetail.book": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to BookShopApp.Models.Book. Path: $.bookDetail.book | LineNumber: 9 | BytePositionInLine: 20."
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my inputs in Swagger:

Variant #1:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "title": "string",
  "author": "string",
  "count": 0,
  "bookDetail": {
    "id": 0,
    "description": "string",
    "bookId": 0,
    "book": "string"
  }
}
```

Variant #2:

```
{
  "title": "Book Title",
  "author": "Author Name",
  "count": 3,
  "bookDetail": {
    "description": "Book Description"
  }
}
```

I thought that this would fix my problem but it really did not:

```
// in Program.cs
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

Please help!

PS: at the moment I do not want to use DTOs.

Comment: The property `book` in `bookDetail` is of type `book` and not of type `string`

Comment: @MatterOfFact I know it. How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to fix ASP.NET Core Web API sub object creating problem

1: Remove the`<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file
(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).

**Or** Use your `Variant #2` as request body, then declaring Book and BookDetail Nullable like:

```
public BookDetail? BookDetail { get; set; } 
public Book? Book { get; set; }
```

2.Then use `"[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetByIdAsync")]"` before GetByIdAsync method.

3.And add below code in the Program.cs;

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: No, does not works. Swagger error msg: 
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Books' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_BookDetails_Books_BookId". The conflict occurred in database "BookShopApp_db", table "dbo.Books", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: @DeveloperMister  Don't set book  id if you add the book into database, I just use these form to show you can excute the post method .

Comment: @DeveloperMister  Have a try my update request body.

Comment: no, error: "System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtRouteResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result) "

Comment: @DeveloperMister   my result like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvEmB.png, I don't meet your "No route matches the supplied values" What did you do ? How you get the error ?

Comment: just using Swagger, pass your 'Try' value

Comment: may I sahre you my GitHub Repo?

Comment: @DeveloperMister  Yes , you can.

Comment: @DeveloperMister   To solve "No route matches the supplied values.' Try to add name to your http get GetByIdAsync method. like: `[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetByIdAsync")]`  . Besides, if you have other questions, you can create a new post to describe , so that others can help to solve.

Comment: your last comment really helped me. but is it possible to not delete '<Nullable>enable</Nullable>' and make it work? declaring Book and BookDetail Nullable ( BookDetail? BookDetail { get; set; }, Book? Book { get; set; }) does not helps

Comment: @DeveloperMister   Yes it is possible . You can use your Variant #2: as request body, then declaring Book and BookDetail Nullable   `public BookDetail? BookDetail { get; set; }`   ,  `public Book? Book { get; set; }`

Comment: thanks! please edit your answer, include about "[HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetByIdAsync")]" andyour last comment and add that I need to use: "JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles". I will mark your anser as "Answered"